# Is there a way of rendering rmarkdown to an object directly without saving to disk?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

We are working on a project where following an analysis of data using R, we use rmarkdown to render an html report which will be returned to users uploading the original dataset. This will be part of an online complex system involving multiple steps. One of the requirements is that the rmarkdown html will be serialized and saved in a SQL database for the system to return to users.

My question is - is there a way to render the markdown directly to an object in R to allow for direct serialisation? We want to avoid saving to disk unless absolutely needed as there will be multiple parallel processes doing similar tasks and resources might be limited. From my reasearch so far it doesn't seem possible, but would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it's not possible due to the architecture of rmarkdown.

If you have this level of control over your server, you could create a RAM disk, using part of your the memory to simulate a hard drive. The actual hard disk won't be used.